# Why aren't my blogs showing up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method 'blog' In blogs/index, I have the following code:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
    <h3><%= @blog.try(:title) %></h3>
    <div><%= @blog.try(:body) %></div>
    <% end %>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I got to http://localhost:3000/blogs, nothing is showing up. What is the probelm?

Comment: Can you include your controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<h3><%= @blog.try(:title) %></h3>
<div><%= @blog.try(:body) %></div>
```

Do it:

```
<h3><%= blog.try(:title) %></h3>
<div><%= blog.try(:body) %></div>
```

You used `blog` to iterate so you should use `blog` not `@blog` which is the object.

Comment: Will do, but it makes me wait 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Also, You can use simple, like below:

```
<% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
  <h3><%= blog.title %></h3>
  <div><%= blog.body %></div>
<% end %>
```